# Free library like Java's Robot class for C++

Tags: java, c++, class, awtrobot

Is there a free library that has the same features of Java's Robot class for C++?

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: This sort of thing is probably very specific to the windowing system being used for the application. What platform are you aiming for?

Answer (score 2):

For Linux there is [Dogtail](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/020jun06/features/dogtail/) which uses the accessibility technology of GNOME.
I tried writing some tests for the GNOME calculator. You can use the standard unit test framework of Python to write tests. Dogtail handles all communication with the user interface. All buttons and fields have proper names in GNOME and can be accessed from Python.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there are tools like [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) which can automate a GUI application. On Linux I'm not aware of anything, though; [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) is the gold standard for automating command line applications like telnet, but it doesn't handle GUIs.